# Setup sub platforms inside Unity

Tags: unity, build-process, automation

I want to automate some of my Unity build process. I know that setting up automatic builds for platforms is relatively easy, just start Unity headless and tell it to build platform X!

This is fine for most things however I have some platform specific things for a given platform. For example I have achievements for Steam, GoG and my own thing if you are running truly standalone. I can easy switch between them by setting `#define STEAM_BUILD` to make a build with steam features enabled. This is setup for each platform that I support.

At the moment I have to change the script manually and re-build every time. I want to make a build server do this all for me but **how do I tell Unity to build my PC version with a certain `#define X` set?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Application.RuntimePlatform` to determine in code which platform you're on.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RuntimePlatform.html

You can also specify a build target on the commandline, which will set the appropriate `#define` for the target in question.

`-buildTarget <name>`

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html

The `#defines` are listed here:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html

If you need seperate builds for Windows and Windows with Steam, then you can set other preprocessor definitions in a text asset:

> You can define your own preprocessor directives to control which code
>   gets included when compiling. To do this you must add a text file with
>   the extra directives to the Assets folder. The name of the file
>   depends on the language you are using. The extension is .rsp:      C#
>   (player and editor scripts)   /Assets/mcs.rsp UnityScript
>     /Assets/us.rsp
>
> As an example, if you include the single line -define:UNITY_DEBUG in
>   your mcs.rsp file, the #define directive UNITY_DEBUG exists as a
>   global #define for C# scripts, except for Editor scripts.
>
> Every time you make changes to .rsp files, you need to recompile in
>   order for them to be effective. You can do this by updating or
>   reimporting a single script (.js or .cs) file.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html

Comment: So I would have to edit the `.rsp` file every time that I want to build for a given platform rather than the script? That just moves the problem somewhere else... Or can I have multiple `.rsp` files and selectively use them?

Comment: You can generate the .rsp file with a script. I am speaking from professional Unity game dev experience; it's how we do it at work.

Comment: That makes more sense